# Navbar.Brand unreachable

Tags: reactjs

Hey guys I am trying to set up a Navbar using react bootstrap. I cannot figure out why I am getting a 'parsing error: Unexpected token'. Please advise

**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
const Header = () => {
    return{
        <Navbar bg="light" variant="light">
            <Navbar.Brand href="/">Images Gallery</Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar>
    }
};
export default Header;
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
const Header = () => {
    return (
        <Navbar bg="light" variant="light">
            <Navbar.Brand href="/">Images Gallery</Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar>
    )
};
export default Header;
```

Jsx must be wrapped in () when using that return statement